# How to use the password which got generated in Laravel 5.4 into Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.6, laravel-migrations

I have a application called A which was developed in Laravel 5.4 and having more than 5000 users. I have to migrate the application to Laravel 5.6 without asking them to change the password.

Comment: I would think the hashes generated in 5.4 would be compatible with 5.6.

Comment: That should work fine, just make sure you use the same cipher.

Answer (score 1):

Hashes generated in 5.4 should have used bcrypt, if you did not alter the service provider or bind a different implementation.

Hashes in 5.6 support both bcrypt and argon but default to bcrypt if you did not change the driver in your config/hashing.php file.

Therefore, by default both use bcrypt and should be compatible.

Comment: Wondering how it works when the APP_KEY is different for both the application.
APP_KEY is also considered in registration right?[bcrypt() consider the app_key]

Comment: No, you're confusing hashing with encryption.

Comment: Thanks Devon. I understood the difference now.

Comment: @AlbertRaj great.  Mark this answer as accepted if it looks valid to you.